# HTML/JS/CSS: Modal dialog causes page to scroll/jump

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog, popup

I'm building a variant of the famous [Wordle game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wordle). I have several modal dialogs (i.e. "pop-ups"), that all have css class `modal-large`.

For some reason, one instance of these dialogs causes the page to **jump-scroll** to a different location. When I close this modal dialog, the page returns back to it's initial position.

**Here is a gif demonstrating this behaviour.**

[image]

**This gif first demonstrates two other dialogs of the same css-class that work perfectly, and then the instance of the dialog that **does not** work.**

**I am looking for suggestions on why this undesired jumping/scrolling could be happening, and ideas for troubleshooting.**

I've already inspected with the Chrome DevTools, but so far cannot see anything that is the clear culprit.

For reference, here are the `modal-large` and `modal-large-content` classes

```
.modal-large {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
  border-radius:12px;
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-large-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
  -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: animatetop;
  animation-duration: 0.4s
}
```

and below is the HTML-structure of the faulty dialog.

```
<!-- Game Modal (Game Over, win, etc)-->
<div id="game-modal" class="modal-large" style="z-index:20 !important;">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-large-content">
    <div class="modal-large-header">
      <span id="game-modal-close" class="close">&times;</span>
      <span id="game-modal-header"><h2>Game Modal Header</h2></span>
    </div>
    <div id="game-modal-body" class="modal-large-body">
      
    </div>
    <div id="game-modal-footer" class="modal-large-footer">
      
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

All three dialogs use this structure and the same classes/stylings.

For full disclosure, here are other stylings in use on some parts of this dialog, as per the HTML-structure

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    .modal-large-content 
    {
        width: 420px;
    }
}

/* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
  from {top:-300px; opacity:0} 
  to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

@keyframes animatetop {
  from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
  to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: white;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-large-header {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.modal-large-body {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    text-align: center;
    color:gray;
}

.modal-large-footer {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.shareon > a{
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Can't currently see what even _triggers_ those modals in the first place. And your GIF is way too small to be able to actually see any details. Please present a proper [mre] of the issue.

Comment: Will do later, thanks!